# PHP Loop to Access MySQL Databases

Tags: php, mysql

### I'm trying to figure out how to code a loop in a PHP script that:

1. gets $hostname, $username $password and $platform from an included script for a bunch of MySQL databases (different remote servers with different access credentials) I just have read-only access to
2. runs the PHP script on each of the databases

I have all the variables stored in an array that looks like this:

```
$servers = array(
    'server1' => array(
    'hostname' => '<serverurl>'
    'username' => 'readonly',
    'password' => 'pword',
    'platform' => 'platform'
),
'server2' => array(
    'hostname' => 'serverurl'
    'username' => 'readonly',
    'password' => 'pword',
    'platform' => 'platform'
),
},
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass those values into a loop statement in my PHP script though - how would I make it run on every server in the array?:

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error('Unable to connect to MySQL'));
echo 'Connected to MySQL<br>';
mysql_select_db($platform, $dbhandle) or die(mysql_error('Unable to connect to database'));
echo 'Connected to database<br>';
```

Sorry for the noob question/if this is a repeat - I couldn't find anything similar when I searched. Is there a good site for me to look up this sort of thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$dbhandles = array();

foreach($servers as $server => $details) {
  $dbhandles[$server] = mysql_connect($details['hostname'], $details['username'], $details['password']) or die(mysql_error('Unable to connect to MySQL'));
}
```